# What is the difference between eclipse-cdt and eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

What is the difference between *eclipse-cdt* and *eclipse* IDE?

Comment: The eclipse ide is a generic development framework.  eclipse-cdt is eclipse with the c/c++ plugins for c/c++ development

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse provides IDEs and platforms for nearly every language and   architecture. The *eclipse* package supports Java out of the box and the *eclipse-cdt* package supports C and C++.

- The eclipse package provides the whole Eclipse SDK that contains Eclipse Platform, Java development tools and Plug-in Development Environment, including source and both user and programmer documentation. The best way to install the latest version of Eclipse for Java in Ubuntu 14.04, currently Eclipse Photon, is to install the eclipse snap package as follows:

  ```
  sudo apt install snapd   
  sudo snap install eclipse --classic
  ```
- The eclipse-cdt package contains Eclipse features and plugins that are useful for C and C++ development.

  ```
  sudo apt install eclipse-cdt
  ```